# The most efficient way of reading Exif (LatLng) for gallery images

Tags: android, kotlin, inputstream, exif

I want to get GPS coordinates of all the images in the user gallery. The solution below works, but it takes 15 seconds for 1500 photos in the gallery. Is there a more efficient way? The result shall be an array of all user photos and their locations.

Loading all images (600ms for 1500 photos):

```
resolver.query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    selection,
    selectionArgs,
    sortOrder
)?.use { cursor ->
```

Getting Exif data for each (15s for 1500 photos):

```
fun readExif(resolver: ContentResolver, id: Long): String? {
val contentUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    id,
)

var photoUri = MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(contentUri)
var a: String? = ""
var b: String? = ""
var c: String? = ""
resolver.openInputStream(photoUri)?.use { stream ->
   val exifInterface = ExifInterface(stream);
   a = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME)
   b = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)
   c = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE)
}

return a;
```

}

Comment: You could try [querying the `MediaStore` for the `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` from the `ImageColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns).

Comment: That is unfortunately deprecated

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I should have read the actual docs. I had it my head that they were available with location permissions. In that case, what you have is probably about as good as it is going to get. [Using `getLatLng()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#getlatlong) might be a tiny bit faster, but it is unlikely to help a lot. Frankly, 600ms for 1500 photos suggests sub-millisecond time to open the stream and read in the EXIF headers, which is impressive.